# Cucumber-jvm scenarios execution results in real time progress

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Is there any plugin or tool in Cucumber-JVM to watch or view the realtime execution results of scenarios when we execute in Maven build? I know in IDE we can watch it but not on Maven Build

At the moment I have arroung 120 scenarios and the build takes arround one hour to finish the execution. I wan't to see the realtime status of scenarios (passed/failed) in the middle of execution.

Earlier I have integrated cucumber scenarios using [TestRail](http://www.gurock.com/testrail/) to view the execution status in realtime by keeping the test rail id in scenario and getting . But I am looking something cucumber specific.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your needs you may want to run cucumber with the `progress` or `pretty` plugin. You can do this from the command-line with `--plugin progress` or through `@CucumberOptions`.

If you need more, the appropriate way to do this would be to a custom plugin that listens to the execution of cucumber features. There is no documentation but the source of the existing plugins is fairly straight forward.

Comment: I will try on this. Thanks for answering

Comment: I have configured it to display in txt file. And here is the output `[32m.[0m[32m.[0m[32m.[0m[31mF[0m`  But not sure how to interpret this

Comment: Try the monochrome option

Comment: I getting `......................` in the text file. Here is my configuration     
 `"progress:target/Progress.txt",` with `monochrome=true` in Cucumber java runner file

Comment: So Progress is just dots? Or is it a fixed amount of dots? Can't find docu about it.

Comment: One dot per scenario.